# Is there an option to specify the JRE location to be used by the installer?

Tags: java, install4j

We have a a Linux installer with bundled 64-bit JRE.

One user is still on Ubuntu 16 32-bit. The installer does not run (as expected):

[image]

We were wondering if we could provide a workaround to get the installer to run anyway, like a [command line option](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/installers/options.html) for the installer to provide the JRE location to use.

We also tried installing a 32-bit JRE via apt-get and were hoping that the installer would [fall back to the standard JRE search locations](https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/doc/installers/jre.html), but it only tries the unpacked bundled JRE.

Comment: You should provide a 32 bit download, bundled with a 32bit jre and a 64 bit downlod bundled with a 64 bit jre. Most software packages offer a choice to the customer which version they opt to download

Comment: @Tschallacka yes, of course. We decided to drop the 32-bit installer a while ago. Now I'm just wondering about a manual workaround for a single user.

Comment: You'll need to provide the user a jar without bundled installer.

Comment: You probably mean an installer without a bundled JRE. That would work, yes, just like providing an installer with a bundled 32-bit JRE. But we don't want to provide (and manage) any additional installers. Just wondering if there is a way to get this existing installer to work somehow.

Comment: With a special installer that strips the jre when a flag is used. `install.sh --32bit` that then first strips all runtime things from the downloaded installer, and then install it with the existing runtime

Comment: Yes good idea. But not confident this is even possible. The installer binary probably contains logic that expects the bundled JRE and would fail trying to unpack it. Before going that route, it would be less effort to compile a one-off installer without bundled JRE for that user.

Comment: Yes, add a fee. if the customer has outdated specs for the system, add a fee for the support, or let them upgrade to a support tier for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 9.x there is no way to do that. I've added a feature request to our issue tracker.

Comment: Thanks. It's not very important. I thought maybe there was an undocumented option. Maybe also consider falling back to the default search sequence if the bundled JRE is not compatible (or an option to enable this fallback mechanism instead of providing a specific location).